# Pattern match list cons quotation

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a generalised condition evaluator, similar to what the Lisp/Scheme people call [`cond`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html#%28part._cond%29), using quotations because they are the easiest way to get call-by-name semantics. I'm having trouble pattern-matching against the list cons operation, and can't seem to find out exactly how to represent it. Here's what I have so far:

```
open FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let rec cond = function
  | NewUnionCase (Cons, [NewTuple [condition; value]; tail]) ->
    if QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate <| Expr.Cast(condition)
      then QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate <| Expr.Cast(value)
      else cond tail

  | _ -> raise <| MatchFailureException ("cond", 0, 0
```

The problem is with the `Cons` identifier in the first branch of the pattern match--it doesn't exist, and I can't figure out how to represent the list `::` data constructor.

What is the correct way to pattern match against the list cons data constructor?

Comment: Why quotations? Why not functions?

Comment: And come to think of it, why implement such a thing at all? What's wrong with `if - then - elif - else`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, quotations (`<@ ... @>`) are faster to type than functions (`fun () -> ...`), and can be destructured and manipulated more easily. As to the overall justification, I'm trying to justify that we don't need new syntax for https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way of writing `Cons` in the pattern directly, but you can use `when` clause to check whether the union case is a case named `"Cons"` of the `list<T>` type:

```
let rec cond = function
  | NewUnionCase (c, [NewTuple [condition; value]; tail]) 
      when c.Name = "Cons" && c.DeclaringType.IsGenericType &&
        c.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ list> -> 
      Some(condition, value, tail)
  | _ -> 
      None
```